# android native send button icon

Tags: android, icons

May I know where I could find Android native send button icon? Like the one used in hangout/message.

[image: Send button icon]

I found one in android.R.drawble.ic_menu_send but the color is different.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Color depends on theme you use so if you need white icon holo_dark is your theme. Alternatively you may download entire icon pack from Android website

http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20120814.zip

White version is in Android_Design_Icons_20120711/All_Icons/holo_dark/hdpi/6_social_send_now.png

Answer (score 3):

The answer is correct but outdated, as with release of Android 5, [Material Design icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases) are now the preferred alternative. As of May 2015, the latest version is [Material Design Icons 1.0.1](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases/download/1.0.1/material-design-icons-1.0.1.zip).

Answer (score 0):

you can find icon here
https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/61680-200.png

check it on google also

Answer (score 0):

Or a 3rd option, material.io:

- https://material.io/icons/#ic_send
- [ic_send_black_24px.svg](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-icons/external-assets/v4/icons/svg/ic_send_black_24px.svg)